# Reusing reducer logic, action name is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I'm looking at this documentation page: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic on redux. I'm trying to implement something like this:

```
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function createNamedWrapperReducer(reducerFunction, reducerName) {
  return (state, action) => {
    const { name } = action
    const isInitializationCall = state === undefined
    if (name !== reducerName && !isInitializationCall) return state

    return reducerFunction(state, action)
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  counterA: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'A'),
  counterB: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'B'),
  counterC: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'C')
})
```

However I don't understand how to get the name from `action`. And this code is not working on my project as `const { name } = action` is returning `undefined`.

What I'm I missing? Is this example complete? How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you dispatching your action? The action should be an object with a `name` property

Comment: Those are just examples of reducers without any action dispatching example, so somewhere in your code you need to have `dispatch({type: 'INCREMENT', name: 'A'})`

Comment: Is that the only way to do this?